# Auto-update all github repositories when I commit

Tags: git, github

I have multiple systems interconnected by SSH with the same repository cloned on them . I want to update the files on the PCs everytime I commit something and I don't have acces to github actions. Is this possible ?

Comment: How are these systems interconnected? SSH? HTTPS? Network filesystems?

Comment: They are connected by SSH

Comment: You can run your own CI/CD — there are many self-hosted solutions, big and small. Gitlab-on-premise, Jenkins, etc.

Comment: I would design a tree of hosts that know each other and push to each other. After a commit I'd push to host A on which `post-update` hook pushes to B and C on which their hooks push to X, Y, Z, W. I'd document the tree thoroughly so that I could easily restructure the tree. And [push to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+push+to+deploy).

Comment: This would allow me to distribute the workload. There is no a single host that does all the pushes.

Comment: I allready have jenkins , but it is not integrated with git at all